# New menu for comments with "common phrases or questions"

Tags: discussion

We get lots of questions which are either not filled in correctly, not formatted correctly, off topic, not enough detail etc

I try to be useful and write something like "there is a problem with your post because of X, please *edit your post*" where edit your post is click-able.

Other times, I explain the question is likely off topic and provide a link to the help section.

Taking the time to make the comments clear is time consuming and I'm assuming it's not just me making the effort.

Can we add a context menu so we can right click in the comments box (or have a new icon (however it's done)) where we can add common phrases / questions.

```
1. Please see the help section for more information. (where the link is already created)
2. Please edit your post and add this information (where edit this post is a link).
3. Please read this post to see "how to write a good question"
4. Please read this post to understand the XY problem
5. A direct link to LMGTFY ( :) )
6. A direct link to "what have you tried" ( :) )
7. etc
```

(OK, 2 of those are a joke, but you get the point)

The idea of the text above is to aid the text you're writing, not to be a total comment. So, I could write (as an example) as a comment:

> "Your post lacks clarity, what OS is this and have you tried X? Auto-Enter-Bullet-2

The reason for this is, when a post is closed it IS a kick in the teeth. It's the websites way of saying "go away, we don't want you. And although we pretend you can fix it where we will re-open it, we all know you probably won't update it because you're annoyed!"

This means people don't come back etc. By having these things in the comments it *could* be more likely that people will make more of an effort before their post is closed. Being told how they could change their post AFTER it's closed is (IMO) daft! Telling them before I think is much more user friendly and encouraging.

Please note, this would only become active for people above a certain reputation, or a certain number of comments or edits (you choose the criteria).

**EDIT**

Journeyman has answered and explain there is a scrip for it. Whilst an excellent answer, it's also a hack - it's a work around. I don't want to have to install add ons/plugins. I (we) give my (our) own time and effort, so please make it easy for me (us).

Comment: This already exists in the Low Quality Posts review queue, for answers.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I don't leave a comment when I come across a bad question, it's a lot of effort to try to understand the questions and sometimes it's apparent they asker didn't visit the correct areas of "help". But I don't want to type this every time. I also don't want to install anything as I work across several machines.

Answer (score 11):

There's a [script for that](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) - I don't use it myself, though I can see how it would be helpful for folks who *actively* comment.

I prefer to hand craft my comments myself.

I'm not entirely certain its something I want to see universally - people sometimes are a little too impatient and clickhappy, and it may confuse newbies.

Edit (by fixer1234): The version at that link has a problem for sites other than SO.  Use the new release v1.4.0 at this link: [SE-AutoReviewComments/releases/tag/v1.4.0](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments/releases/tag/v1.4.0) (the xpi option is a simple install).  I had some initial problems with the previous version and don't know whether they're inherent in this one.  If you do experience problems, the issue turned out to be other Firefox extensions.  On my computer the culprit was Ghostery, which blocks trackers.  If you have a problem with the script, try disabling ad and tracker blockers for SU.  Disabling Ghostery also restored some missing icons on SU.  An addon called Stylish (assists with themes and skins), was also problematic.

Comment: Sorry I had meant to write it would only be applicable to certain people (edited my post). Yes, I do like to do my comment myself, but just having the link part automatic would be great. So I can write "Please clarify the bit about X and what N are you using. ENTER SCRIPT"

Comment: Yeah, that's what I supposed, and this works perfectly for that use case

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, sorry, it's an excellent answer but, the more I think about it, the more I realise it's a good solution, it's a work around solution :( I'm sorry to remove my 'mark as answer' (naturally you've had a plus 1)

Comment: No worries about that.